# If an opponent uses "PAY DAY", but you win, do you pick up the coins?

Tags: pokemon-series

If you are facing an opponent that has a PokeMon with the move "PAY DAY", but you end up beating the opponent, do you get to keep the coins dropped from the move?

(If this is generation specific, I'd like to know if this applies to Generation 3, as I usually play FireRed and Emerald)

The only information given by my PokeMon summary on Meowth, is this:

[image: Pay Day information]

It doesn't really give much clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Generation 3:

After conducting a small test.  I can confirm that you *do not* keep the coins from an opponent's PAY DAY...  Here is the steps I did to recreate this:

- Go to Route 8 (Kanto) and find the "string" of trainers lined up on the road.  You should be able to recognize them, they're also right next to the twins...
- Battle the second trainer from the bottom, this trainer only uses Meowth...  If they don't use PAY DAY during the battle, then you can use the VS Seeker to rematch them until they do.
- Remember not to use PAY DAY yourself (I screwed up the first time doing this, and I couldn't tell if they dropped the coins or me, or both).

For picture reference,

[image]

Comment: I recall that in gen1 pay day used by an NPC did give money

Comment: I removed the [tag:pokemon-third-gen] tag and titled this question with "Generation 3", I only posted for generation 3 because that's what I most commonly play.  You can conduct the same test and post an answer for gen 1 if you'd like.  :)